# When are reference requests for pastoral advice on topic?

Tags: discussion, pastoral-advice-questions

I'm looking at this question:

[Christian resources to help with Problem with sexual thoughts / addiction](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/62414/christian-resources-to-help-with-problem-with-sexual-thoughts-addiction)

reading the divergent answers and thinking I'd like to hit the close button, but I don't see the question as actually violating any rule specifically (it's just violating every rule, which seems to be an exception to the rule)

I don't want to close the question without leaving some sort of a comment. But,

> I'm sorry, you just violated every rule of this site, your question has no place here, goodbye.

seems like it'll spook the noobs.

Any advice for what to leave when a question is too broad, (technically) pastoral advice and a reference request? Do we leave a series of meta posts, is there a hierarchy?  (seems like pastoral advice is biggest no-no, then too broad is usually bad, then being a reference requests is a gray area)

Answer (score 4):

Reference requests should be sufficiently targetted that you wouldn't expect to get more than half a dozen references in the answers. For something like lust my local Christian bookstore is going to have hundreds of relevant books.

Also, in this case, [PyRulez made a bad edit which did not respect the OP's intentions](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/55461), which should not have been approved. We could just revert to the OP's original post, making it a simple pastoral advice question. I think doing that and deleting all the (extremely denominationally biased) answers would be best.

Comment: Why was my edit bad? I only slightly changed it, and that was to make it on-topic.

Comment: @PyRulez You did it without the OP's approval, and in a way that invalidated the answers.

Comment: you don't need OPs approval, as long as you think it is what they would want.

Comment: @PyRulez that's not true. As evidenced by the fact that a mod reverted your edit.

Comment: @PyRulez See [Should we edit Pastoral Advice questions?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1592/21576)